# Unexpected value setting java calendar minutes

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I am trying to create a time interval, as the starting point is the current time and the minimum and maximum values are calculated by a special variable which is set by the user (upperBound). So the code looks like:

```
private static int upperBound = 1440;
.....
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Now:\t\t\t" + calendar.getTime());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, -upperBound);
System.out.println("After the change:\t" + calendar.getTime());
```

and the output is:

```
Now:            Mon Jan 27 14:53:42 EET 2014
After the change:   Sun Jan 26 14:00:42 EET 2014
```

But I expect to be (after the change): Sun Jan 26 14:***53***:42 EET 2014

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method, not `set`

```
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -upperBound);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .plus( 1440 , ChronoUnit.MINUTES )
```

## Details

The modern way is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy `Calendar` class.

## Using java.time

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

You can add amounts of time to that.

```
Instant later = instant.plus( 24 , ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

If you mean to add specifically minutes, so be it.

```
Instant later = instant.plus( 1440 , ChronoUnit.MINUTES );
```

If you want to add a day in calendar terms, to account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), you must apply a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusDays( 1 );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).